# Parameterize Method Reference in Java

Tags: java, class, methods

I am attempting to use a map to filter strings to the correct methods. The most effective way I have found to construct the map is as follows.

```java
        Map<Predicate<String>, Function<String, Symbol>> temp = new HashMap<Predicate<String>, Function<String, Symbol>>();
        temp.put(SymbolA::boolMethod, SymbolA::stringToSymbol);
        temp.put(SymbolB::boolMethod, SymbolB::stringToSymbol);
        temp.put(SymbolC::boolMethod, SymbolC::stringToSymbol);
```

This allows me to loop through the map entries until I find one where boolMethod(string) is true, at which point I can call stringToSymbol(string).

All of these methods are static, and all the symbol types inherit from the class Symbol.

My question is whether I can create a method so I don't repeat this same line for each symbol type. Ideally it would be something like

```java
Map<Predicate<String>, Function<String, Symbol>> addToMap(Map<Predicate<String>, Function<String, Symbol>> map, Class<? extends Symbol> symbolType) {
        map.put(symbolType::boolMethod, symbolType::stringToSymbol);
        return map;
}
```

The Class object, however, only has getDefinedMethod, which does not seem to work for my purposes.

Is there a way to create this function, initialize this map, or possibly even a better way to filter these strings to the correct symbol types?

Comment: Just use a plain old interface for that.

Comment: Why do you need the `Class` parameter at all? Just define the whole thing as `<T>` and be done.

Comment: Do `SymbolA`, `SymbolB`,  `SymbolC` have a common interface?

Comment: All the symbol types inherit from Symbol, which includes both of these methods. Would an interface be more useful?

Comment: I assume that Symbol instances can have some internal state, that is not every instance of (e.g.) SymbolA is the same as every other SymbolA?

Comment: One suggestion, which doesn't answer your question, but I think improves your design, just have a single method `Optional<Symbol> stringToSymbol(...)` so that you don't repeat any parsing done in `boolMethod`, and reduce the chances of the two methods implementations getting out of sync as you maintain your code.

Comment: Is your application using any dependency injection framework? Another way to do this would be to register a component implementing a factory interface for each of your symbol types.

Comment: @tgdavies that Optional suggestion is very helpful. That should let me reduce it from a map to a list, which is about as compact as this method would have been.